# Node.js extract html elements between tags

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Suppose I have a website with html source code as structured as below :

```
<html>
<head>
....

<table id="xxx">
 <tr>

..
</table>
```

I have already applied the library to dismiss all the html tags. Would you please tell what libraries or regex for me to extract all texts from the html source beginning with `<table>` ... and end with `</table>`

using node.js ?

Below is my code

```
console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port);


var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://fpp.mpfa.org.hk/tc_chi/mpp_list.jsp', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
   var sanitizeHtml = require('sanitize-html');
   var dirty = body.match(/\[(.*)\]/).pop();

var clean = sanitizeHtml(dirty, {
  allowedTags: [  ],
  allowedAttributes: {

  },
  allowedIframeHostnames: ['www.youtube.com']
});

  console.log('body:', clean); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use cheerio's API to get the `<table>` and then print out the text nodes.

Given the following HTML of a page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Contacts</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <section>
            <h2>World</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>foo</td>
                    <td>bar</td>
                    <td>fizz</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>buzz</td>
                    <td>hello</td>
                    <td>world</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

And running the following code:

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const URL_TO_PARSE = "http://localhost/my-page.html";

// Make a request to get the HTML of the page
request(URL_TO_PARSE, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) throw new Error("Something went wrong");
    // Load the HTML into cheerio's DOM
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);
    // Print the text nodes of the <table> in the HTML
    console.log($("table").text());
});
```

Will produce the following output:

```
            foo
            bar
            fizz


            buzz
            hello
            world
```

You can then manipulate it as you like.  Cheerio uses an API very similar to jQuery.

Comment: What if I have got div id as below ? 

<div id="printable">
<table...>
<div id="printable2">
<table ,,> ..